# using chained selectors and methods as options in jquery plugin, confusion about this, $(this) scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

Im trying to setup a jQuery plugin that has one of its options a jquery object using selectors and methods like `find`

here is a stripped down example using the "greenify" tutorial on https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

```js
(function ( $ ) {

  $.fn.greenify = function( options ) {

    // This is the easiest way to have default options.
      var settings = $.extend({
        // These are the defaults.
        backgroundColor: "white"
      }, options );

    // Greenify the collection based on the settings variable.
      return this.each(function(){
        $(this).find(settings.target).css({
          backgroundColor: settings.backgroundColor
        });
      });

  };

}( jQuery ));


$(".target").greenify({
  target: $(".something").eq(1).find(".another"),
  backgroundColor: "red"
});
```

```css
.target * {
padding: 10px;
margin: 10px;
background: blue;
border: 4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="target">
target

  <div class="something">
  something
    <div class="another">another</div>
  </div>

  <div class="something">
  something
    <div class="another">another</div>
  </div>

  <div class="something">
  something
    <div class="another">another</div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="target">
target

  <div class="something">
  something
    <div class="another">another</div>
  </div>

  <div class="something">
  something
    <div class="another">another</div>
  </div>

  <div class="something">
  something
    <div class="another">another</div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="target">
target

  <div class="something">
  something
    <div class="another">another</div>
  </div>

  <div class="something">
  something
    <div class="another">another</div>
  </div>

  <div class="something">
  something
    <div class="another">another</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the desired result? Color all `another` children with red?

Comment: @Akrion yes. the issue I'm having with my plugin, is passing a jquery object through as options. but that seems to be working in this simplified version.  But in this example its only doing the first `.target` it finds, or so it seems.

Comment: @Akrion im sorry, no. only the second ".something .another", specifically using jquery selectors and methods in the options

Comment: Every second  `.something . another`?

Comment: yes, specifically using methods in the options.  The plugin needs to be able to use advanced jquery selectors and methods to target specific elements
`target: $(".class").method()`

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass a selector to your plugin which `should` be then evaluated (**in the context of your plugin**).

The issue is jQuery evaluates your selector **first** and then passes the result to your plugin so you are left with whatever is that result (in your case only 1 element since you used `eq(1)`). Your `$(this)` works as expected just the data fed into the plugin is already filtered.

Also I looked over the article you provided but there they only ever pass a collection of elements (via the selector) and then do something with that context which to me seems what you should do as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to change the target to a selector string instead of a jQuery object? The use of `.eq(1)` is selecting against the entire DOM, so only the first of all the `'.somtehing'` will be matched.

If you call it like:

```
$(".target").greenify({
  target: '.something:eq(1) .another',
  backgroundColor: "red"
});
```

That should do what you want.

Another way would be to use [:nth-child](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) instead:

```
$(".target").greenify({
  target: $('.something:nth-child(2)').find('.another'),
  backgroundColor: "red"
});
```

just note that nth-child is 1 indexed, rather than 0.

Comment: the second example wont work, because the plugin needs to be able to use jquery methods,  like `.first()`, `.parent()`, `.siblings()`

Comment: im not quite sure how you expect the first example to function?

Comment: The first example will pass a selector string to `.find` in your function which will be compiled for each `'.target'`

Comment: then you wouldn't be able to use `:eq` since the string would have to be a valid css selector.  You then also lose the ability to use jquery methods.

Comment: It has to be a valid jQuery selector, so you can use things added like `:eq` and `:even`. The only problem with using jQuery functions is they are compiled when you execute the function, so things like `.first()` and `.eq(0)` will match the global first element